# Should I repeat the "for" after each verb?

Tags: grammaticality

Are both of these correct? If they are, is one better than the other?

They need a solution they believe in and can fight for, work for, and live for.

They need a solution they believe in and can fight, work, and live for.

Thanks!

Comment: They're both fine. You can choose which one you think sounds more likely to hammer the message home.

Comment: It sounds pretty grandiose for a mere *solution*.  An English-speaking audience would find this more comic than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  think the difference between them is the following:

When you use "for" after each verb, you add emphasis and a little formality.  In addition, when you use "for" after each verb, you create "alliteration" (e.g. the repetition of identical consonant sounds, most often the sounds beginning words, in close proximity). To me, the alliteration makes the phrase more sophisticated (and emphatic, especially if you said it out loud (as opposed to writing).

When you don't repeat the "for", your sentence sounds less formal and less emphatic.

Hope that helps.